# curl-config error during installation of package

Tags: apt, curl

While installing free radius protobuf package  I am getting this error

```
root@ggns2egl01:/tmp/rlm_protobuf-freeradius-2.1.x# ./configure
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for ranlib... ranlib
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for curl-config... no
*** The curl-config script could not be found. Make sure it is
*** in your path, and that curl is properly installed.
*** Or see http://curl.haxx.se/
configure: error: Library requirements (curl) not met.
```

I installed curl package but getting same error

my Machine details are as follows

```
# uname -a
Linux ggns2egl01 3.2.0-23-generic #36-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 10 20:39:51 UTC 2012 x86_64  x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I also tried to install packages which have curl-config command but those packages have lots of dependencies

```
root@ggns2egl01:/tmp/rlm_protobuf-freeradius-2.1.x# curl-config
The program 'curl-config' can be found in the following packages:
* libcurl4-gnutls-dev
* libcurl4-nss-dev
* libcurl4-openssl-dev

root@ggns2egl01:/tmp/rlm_protobuf-freeradius-2.1.x# apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
curl : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.2 is to be installed
libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.15-0ubuntu10) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.2 is to be installed
libcurl3 : Depends: libc6 (>= 2.17) but 2.15-0ubuntu10.2 is to be installed
libcurl4-gnutls-dev : Depends: libcurl3-gnutls (= 7.22.0-3ubuntu4.1) but 7.22.0-3ubuntu4 is to be installed
                   Depends: libgnutls-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libidn11-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libkrb5-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: libldap2-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: librtmp-dev but it is not going to be installed
                   Depends: zlib1g-dev but it is not going to be installed
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this command to install all the dependencies

```
sudo apt-get build-dep <package>
```

For my situation, it is

```
sudo apt-get build-dep curl
```